# Eclipse p2 director application without updates

Tags: eclipse, p2

I'm installing artefacts through the p2 director application from a command line and all of their repositories will get added to the Software Updates. Is there a way not the get the repositories added, or remove/disable them afterwards?

Comment: I have not tested it yet, but maybe you have to restore the files in `p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings`.

Comment: Thank you @howlger. Do you want to post it as an answer? so I can accept it. It's not the cleanest way doing it or exactly what I was hopping for, but it is automated and from the command line and probably what I ask for it's not possible.

Comment: I removed the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs and org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs in p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings and then I did the same in p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/SDKProfile.profile/.data/.settings  For good measure I deleted the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache as well, hope this should end up in clean product ready to be bundled as installer.

Comment: As far as I know, the p2 cache is not related to this issue. But it should be okay to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p2 director stores the locations of the repositories in the two files

- org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs
- org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs

in each of the following two directories:

- `p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings` and
- `p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/<profileName>.profile/.data/.settings`

Restoring these files might do the trick.

Note, adding the repositories (alias software/update sites) is not a side-effect of using the p2 director, but explicit specified via the [touchpoint action `addRepository`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html) in the metadata repository (`content.xml`/`content.jar`) as part of the installed feature.

Comment: Hi @howlger so the Eclipse I was working on is finalized, you were saying you would like to see it when it's finished. Is there a way to contact you privately so I can send you links?

Comment: OK, thanks.  I got your email, I will message you in a few minutes. You might want to delete the comment probably.