# RCP update via p2 over http

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

Is there a way to force p2 to update an RCP application that is already deployed over http (non-secure) rather than https?  Something like a configuration / command line / eclipse.ini switch?

The application in question was shipped a long time ago with an embedded java keystore that has an expired SSL cert and now fails when trying to update.

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ change the location URL of the update site from `https` to `http`. This works only if the server does not redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks.   Good suggestion.  Unfortunately the product shipped with headless updates.  No p2 UI included.

Comment: Does editing the update sites locations in `p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/` fix your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171578/6505250